# my app becomes larger and larger using CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

I'm working on a hobby project, as i'm a newly developer (2 years), it's my second time EVER, that i'm using Core Data in my projects,

**About the project:**

Tt's a fairly simple app in which you take photos and save them with a keyword.

**My problem:**

Every time I'm trying to remove an item from my tableview:

```
context.delete(myDataArray[indexPath.row])
tableView.beginUpdates()
myDataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
let myIndexPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.row, section: 0)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [myIndexPath], with: .left)
tableView.endUpdates()
dataManager(.save)
```

It goes as i wish, checking my `coreDataFile.sqlite` the data is removed correctly. despite all of that, the app keeps growing. also I tried to clear the cache and tmp folders, but it didn't help.

As I'm new to software development, I would like to offer my apologies in case I'm not expressing my issue correctly.

thank you.

Comment: where you store that photos in gallery or in document folder?

Comment: i encode using `NSData(data: Image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!) as Data` them as `Binary Data` and save them in my persistent container.

Comment: did you remove that things when you remove the record?

Comment: To clarify your post: When you say *the app keeps growing*, what do you mean?  By default, in recent-year versions of Core Data, the SQLite database consists of three files: .sqlite, .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal.  Usually you should not worry about the sizes of these.  What numbers are you seeing and why are you worried?  Also, what is *cache ND tmp folders*?

Comment: @Jerry Krinock thank you for your reply! as i mentioned earlier i'm a newly developer, there are times that i find it too difficult to express my issues on stackoverflow, therefore my apologies. When i build the app on my iPhone under app Documents and & Data, the app keeps increasing it's size even though i've removed all of the elements from my Data Base, when i build and run the app on simulator and check the documents folder it's size stays Zero 0KB. That's why i'm so confused!

Comment: You shouldn't be storing data in core data. Instead use documents folder to save your files and keep their path in your data base.

Comment: Joseph, I still don't know what you mean by *the app keeps increasing its size*.  What indications lead you to say this?  Where do you see this *size*?  What is the size before you do something? What is the size after?  What is the *something* that you do to make the size increase?